# Header and footer not rendering properly in the PDF report's landscape page - jsreport

Tags: pdf-generation, landscape, jsreport, page-numbering, headerfooter

The header and the footer are not getting rendered properly on the landscape page of the report.
The page number is not in sequence, the footer is not rendered completely and the header is not visible.

This is my workspace:

https://playground.jsreport.net/w/jitendra.shah/hMH2MZxZ

As per the requirement, we need to add a landscape page in the report conditionally in the afterRender function. However, on the landscape page, the header is not rendered, page numbers are not in the sequence and footer styling is not getting applied properly to the whole page.